# Graph API .net SDK - Filter Me.MemberOf based on displayName of groups

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to filter out the groups of a user he is a member of based on some words that the group name may contain.

I am using this code -

```
 var groups = _graphServiceClient.Me.MemberOf.Request().Filter($"displayName -eq 'abhi'").GetAsync().Result;
```

but I am getting the error that filter request is invalid.
Any help with this is always appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on aad advanced queries [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries) your request is supported when the request headers contains `ConsistencyLevel` = eventual and `count` = true

To get it to work here is the sample code:

```
List<Option> options = new List<Option>();
options.Add(new HeaderOption("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual"));
options.Add(new QueryOption("$filter", $"displayName eq 'abhi'"));
options.Add(new QueryOption("$count", "true"));


var groups = await graphServiceClient.Me
  .MemberOf
  .Request(options)
  .GetAsync();
```